# Graph isomoprhims

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

Assume that graphs $G$ and $H$ are isomorphic and that $f$ is an isomorphism from $G$ to $H$.

The distance between two vertices is the length of the
shortest path between them. Show that the distance from $v$ to $u$
in $G$ is the same as the distance from $f(u)$ to $f(v)$. Here the graph $G$ has unweighed edges, so how do I prove this ?

I thought about proving this by contradiction.

Without loss of generality, we assume that the distance from $f(u)$ to $f(v)$ is bigger than the distance from $u$ to $v$ and try to reach a contradiction.

if the distance of $f(u)$ to $f(v)$ is bigger then this means that the path is bigger , for example $f(u) \space f(a) \space f(b) \space f(c) \space f(v)$.

But the path from $u$ to $v$ might be $u \space a \space b \space v$ and so now this means that $f(b) \space f(v)$ is an edge in $G$ but not an edge in $H$ and so this means that $f$ is not an isomorphism and hence proved.

Is this argument correct ?

Comment: Your argument looks sound to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your argument seems correct, but a shorter argument would be to say that if $P$ is the shortest path from $u$ to $v$, then $f(P)$ is a path from $f(u)$ to $f(v)$ that has the same length as $P$. If there existed a shorter path $P'$ from $f(u)$ to $f(v)$, then $f^{-1}(P')$ is a path from $u$ to $v$ shorter that $P$. Contradiction.